# Handling Related List Security in Override VF pages

Tags: visualforce, permissions, related-list, relationships, page-override

We have created an Override VF page for an object (for e.g. "Parent Object").
There is an object (for e.g. "Child Object"), which has lookup relation ship with "Parent Object".

On Override page we are showing child object related list by using below code :

```
  <apex:relatedlist list="ChildObject__r" title="Child Records"/>
```

This page works well if user has permission to both objects "Parent Object" and "Child Object".

But, it throws error when parent object has access but child object doesn't.

> "ChildObject__r' is not a valid child relationship name for entity
>   Parent Object"

In Standard Salesforce page, it doesn't show the related list if child object doesn't have access to that page, it doesn't throws run time error.

Is there anyway through which we can auto hide related list in VF page, if user doesn't have access to child object? Because this page is using Standard Controller, I don't have much control over APEX part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may consider trying this:

```
<apex:relatedlist list="ChildObject__r" title="Child Records" rendered="{!$ObjectType.ChildObject__c.accessible}"/>
```

This would check if the loggedIn user has access on this object.
Let me know if this works.

**Note :** Here ChildObject__c is the API name of object.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Rajeev Shekhar 's suggetion I tried above solution.

Only one change was required in above code is :

```
<apex:relatedlist list="ChildObject__r" title="Child Records" rendered="{!$ObjectType.ChildObject__c.accessible}"/>
```

With **ChildObject__r** it throw below error :
        Error: Unknown property '$ObjectType.LIHTC_Note__r' 
So, we need to use "**ChildObject__c**" (API Name of Object).

Comment: Great.. I simply copied that object name and forgot to raplace __r by __c.